# Challenges with complex JSON and Logic App

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I have a challenge with a Logic App I haven't been able to solve. The idea of the app is to

1. take an XML file stored as a binary file to blob storage and JSONify it (Parse JSON action)
2. loop through the "Values" array in the JSON and add a column with certain value on each round (Compose action) and append the output into an array variable
3. store the array variable to CSV (Create CSV table action) and upload the file into data lake

This is easy with a simple JSON, but in our case the schema is very complex.
The first step seems to work as we get a JSON that includes what we need in an array "Values". But it might be that the schema here needs some tweaking as we run into problems later. The resulting JSON is down below.
Where I run into problems is the second step:
[image: For each loop]

Here I get the following error:
*ExpressionEvaluationFailed. The execution of template action 'For_each' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@body('Parse_JSON')?['diffgr:diffgram']?['Results']?['Values']' is of type 'Null'. The result must be a valid array.*

I tried also reading the Values into an array variable but it just confirms that we really do not get the actual data rows from under the "Values" tag in the JSON as the output is just empty brackets:
[image]

Below are the details of the Parse JSON action and the resulting JSON to help in understanding the problem.

**Parse JSON action**

Content: `Json(Xml(base64ToString(body('Get_blob_content')?['$content'])))`

Schema:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "diffgr:diffgram": {
            "properties": {
                "@@xmlns:diffgr": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "@@xmlns:msdata": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Results": {
                    "properties": {
                        "Properties": {
                            "properties": {
                                "@@diffgr:id": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "@@msdata:rowOrder": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "@@stepped": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "Values": {
                            "items": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "@@diffgr:id": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "@@msdata:rowOrder": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "@@status": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "@@ts": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "@@value": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "required": [
                                    "@@diffgr:id",
                                    "@@msdata:rowOrder",
                                    "@@ts",
                                    "@@value",
                                    "@@status"
                                ],
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "xs:schema": {
            "properties": {
                "@@id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "@@xmlns": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "@@xmlns:msdata": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "@@xmlns:xs": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "xs:element": {
                    "properties": {
                        "@@msdata:IsDataSet": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "@@msdata:Locale": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "@@name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "xs:complexType": {
                            "properties": {
                                "xs:choice": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@maxOccurs": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "@@minOccurs": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "xs:element": {
                                            "items": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "@@msdata:Locale": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "@@name": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "xs:complexType": {
                                                        "properties": {
                                                            "xs:attribute": {
                                                                "items": {
                                                                    "properties": {
                                                                        "@@msdata:Caption": {
                                                                            "type": "string"
                                                                        },
                                                                        "@@name": {
                                                                            "type": "string"
                                                                        },
                                                                        "@@type": {
                                                                            "type": "string"
                                                                        }
                                                                    },
                                                                    "required": [
                                                                        "@@name",
                                                                        "@@msdata:Caption",
                                                                        "@@type"
                                                                    ],
                                                                    "type": "object"
                                                                },
                                                                "type": "array"
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        "type": "object"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "required": [
                                                    "@@name",
                                                    "@@msdata:Locale",
                                                    "xs:complexType"
                                                ],
                                                "type": "object"
                                            },
                                            "type": "array"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "type": "object"
                                }
                            },
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

**JSON we get as a result from Parse JSON**

```
{
    "body": {
        "?xml": {
            "@version": "1.0",
            "@encoding": "utf-8"
        },
        "DataSet": {
            "xs:schema": {
                "@id": "Results",
                "@xmlns": "",
                "@xmlns:xs": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
                "@xmlns:msdata": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata",
                "xs:element": {
                    "@name": "Results",
                    "@msdata:IsDataSet": "true",
                    "@msdata:Locale": "",
                    "xs:complexType": {
                        "xs:choice": {
                            "@minOccurs": "0",
                            "@maxOccurs": "unbounded",
                            "xs:element": [
                                {
                                    "@name": "Values",
                                    "@msdata:Locale": "",
                                    "xs:complexType": {
                                        "xs:attribute": [
                                            {
                                                "@name": "ts",
                                                "@msdata:Caption": "81000-F901C Trend ts (81000-F901C)",
                                                "@type": "xs:dateTime"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "@name": "value",
                                                "@msdata:Caption": "81000-F901C Trend value (81000-F901C)",
                                                "@type": "xs:float"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "@name": "status",
                                                "@msdata:Caption": "81000-F901C Trend status (81000-F901C)",
                                                "@type": "xs:string"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "@name": "Properties",
                                    "@msdata:Locale": "",
                                    "xs:complexType": {
                                        "xs:attribute": {
                                            "@name": "stepped",
                                            "@type": "xs:int"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "diffgr:diffgram": {
                "@xmlns:msdata": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata",
                "@xmlns:diffgr": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1",
                "Results": {
                    "Values": [
                        {
                            "@diffgr:id": "Values1",
                            "@msdata:rowOrder": "0",
                            "@ts": "2020-09-02T00:00:00+03:00",
                            "@value": "1.41233063",
                            "@status": "Good"
                        },
                        {
                            "@diffgr:id": "Values2",
                            "@msdata:rowOrder": "1",
                            "@ts": "2020-09-02T01:00:00+03:00",
                            "@value": "1.5102241",
                            "@status": "Good"
                        },
                        {
                            "@diffgr:id": "Values3",
                            "@msdata:rowOrder": "2",
                            "@ts": "2020-09-02T02:00:00+03:00",
                            "@value": "1.18518186",
                            "@status": "Good"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Properties": {
                        "@diffgr:id": "Properties1",
                        "@msdata:rowOrder": "0",
                        "@stepped": "0"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is something wrong with your `schema`, please use this `schema`:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "body": {
            "properties": {
                "?xml": {
                    "properties": {
                        "@@encoding": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "@@version": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "DataSet": {
                    "properties": {
                        "diffgr:diffgram": {
                            "properties": {
                                "@@xmlns:diffgr": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "@@xmlns:msdata": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Results": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "Properties": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "@@diffgr:id": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "@@msdata:rowOrder": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "@@stepped": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "type": "object"
                                        },
                                        "Values": {
                                            "items": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "@@diffgr:id": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "@@msdata:rowOrder": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "@@status": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "@@ts": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "@@value": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "required": [
                                                    "@@diffgr:id",
                                                    "@@msdata:rowOrder",
                                                    "@@ts",
                                                    "@@value",
                                                    "@@status"
                                                ],
                                                "type": "object"
                                            },
                                            "type": "array"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "type": "object"
                                }
                            },
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "xs:schema": {
                            "properties": {
                                "@@id": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "@@xmlns": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "@@xmlns:msdata": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "@@xmlns:xs": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "xs:element": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@msdata:IsDataSet": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "@@msdata:Locale": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "@@name": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "xs:complexType": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "xs:attribute": {
                                                    "items": {
                                                        "properties": {
                                                            "@@msdata:Caption": {
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            },
                                                            "@@name": {
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            },
                                                            "@@type": {
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        "required": [
                                                            "@@name",
                                                            "@@msdata:Caption",
                                                            "@@type"
                                                        ],
                                                    "type": "object"
                                                    },
                                                "type": "array"
                                                }
                                            },
                                        "type": "object"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "type": "object"
                                }
                            },
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```